# How to use value on SpinEdit control with a button in Lazarus

Tags: button, listbox, lazarus

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the value that a user inputs into a SpinEdit control. Basically theres two spinedit controls on the form - one called Crates and the other called Items, How do i use these values entered in a procedure in a calculate button which then displays the entered values in the listbox?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Listbox.add( inttostr( Crates.Value * Items.value ) );

HTH. You sound new to programming: try stuff. One learns a lot from experimentation and mistakes...its the only path to mastery.